# I can't reproduce and correct errors like in the Android Crash Log

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Apparently when people took screenshots in the private profile and then returned immediately to the work profile to our app, the application crashed as soon as they set the focus on an EditText field.

Crashlytics:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: No access to content://com.sec.android.semclipboardprovider/images: neither user 15010223 nor current process has android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
       at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2088)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2056)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
       at android.sec.clipboard.IClipboardService$Stub$Proxy.getClipData(IClipboardService.java:959)
       at com.samsung.android.content.clipboard.SemClipboardManager.getLatestClip(SemClipboardManager.java:609)
       at android.widget.EditText.updateClipboardFilter(EditText.java:316)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:2131)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.checkFocus(InputMethodManager.java:2452)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(InputMethodManager.java:1581)
       at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.showSoftInput(InputMethodManager.java:1512)
       at com.mobileapp.util.UIUtils.showSoftKeyboard(UIUtils.java:288)
       at com.mobileapp.customviews.TopUpAccountView$2.onClick(TopUpAccountView.java:126)
```

Comment: Looks like your app is trying to access the screenshot taken on the parent profile from the work profile (I'm guessing `content://com.sec.android.semclipboardprovider/images` is the Content Provider with that device's screenshots). The work profile is not supposed to be able to access data on the parent profile.

Comment: Have you got any solution regarding this? I'm getting this exception too. Seems like this is happening due to the bug in the Samsung clipboard manager. [Samsung Developer Forum](https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/securityexception-on-emm-device-when-focusing-edittext-in-work-profile-after-taking-screenshot-in-private-profile/12971)